# Join/merge two excel files in asp.net and display them in gridview

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am trying to merge two excel files in asp.net and display them in gridview as one table. The code below is displaying only one table. Can anyone tell me what is the problem with the code below? If you have a better idea please let me know.

```
protected void MergTables()
        {
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[hwTypes].ConnectionString;
            OleDbConnection DBConnection = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            DBConnection.Open();
            OleDbCommand DBCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", DBConnection);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(DBCommand);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("Stock");
            da.Fill(ds, "HWTypes");
            DBConnection.Close();
            string _stockConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[stockConn].ConnectionString;
            DBConnection = new OleDbConnection(_stockConn);
            DBConnection.Open();
            DBCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Stock_voorlopig$]", DBConnection);
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(DBCommand);
            da.Fill(ds, "Stock");

            DBConnection.Close();
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["HWTypes"].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                ds.Tables["HWTypes"].Rows[i]["ProductID"] = ds.Tables["Stock"].Rows[i]["Partno"];
            }

            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Stock"];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using just a single `DataTable` in your `GridView` and you haven't yet joined both.

Here's an approach which uses `Linq-To-DataSet` to join both tables and creates an anonymous type as datasource for the `GridView`.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("Stock");
using (var dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
using (var dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", dbConnection))
using (var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbCommand))
{
    da.Fill(ds, "HWTypes");
}

using (var dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(stockConn))
using (var dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Stock_voorlopig$]", dbConnection))
using (var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbCommand))
{
    da.Fill(ds, "Stock");
}

var joined = from rType in ds.Tables["HWTypes"].AsEnumerable()
             join rStock in ds.Tables["Stock"].AsEnumerable()
             on rType.Field<string>("ProductID") equals rStock.Field<string>("Partno")
             select new
             {
                 ProductID = rType.Field<string>("ProductID")
                 // add the other columns you need here
             };


GridView1.DataSource = joined;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Hi Tim,
I have another question for your. It is the same thing as above but now I would like to display two columns, one from "Sheet1" and one from "Stock_voorlopig$", in a dropdownlist.DataTextField = "FullName", for example. (eg: Select ProductID +' - ' + Name +' - ' as HWTypeFullName), how can I do that?

Comment: @IForti: Just select these  fields where i have commented my code with `// add the other columns you need here`. Then you can use the anonymous type as datasource for your DropDownList and set the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` accordingly to the names of the properties in the anonymous type (like `ProductID` above).

Comment: Thanks again for your help. One more question. Do you know how can I add the Linq query result above - ie: joined- into a datatable or dataset so that I can query the datatabe or the dataset?

Comment: @IForti: i don't understand the question. Why do you need to join something when you want to query it from the database anyway? Or do you want to update the database from the result above somehow? Maybe you need to ask another quation since it's difficult to answer in the comments.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks a gain for your help. I will put it in the question above.

Comment: Hi Tim, I created a second post. Can you have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951331/reuse-linq-result-by-adding-it-in-a-datatable-or-dataset? thank you