# Reuse Linq result by adding it in a datatable or dataset

Tags: asp.net, linq

**strong text**Thanks to Tim who provided me the code below in this other post: [Join/merge two excel files in asp.net and display them in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929780/join-merge-two-excel-files-in-asp-net-and-display-them-in-gridview).

My question in this new post is: 
How can I reuse or add linq result to a dataset or datatabe so that I can query the new table and not the two separate tables? The join keyword gave me the possibility to join the two tables. Now I would like to use this joined table to run other queries on it.

I hope my question makes sense. If you need more info, please let me know.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("Stock");
using (var dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
using (var dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", dbConnection))
using (var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbCommand))
{
    da.Fill(ds, "HWTypes");
}

using (var dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(stockConn))
using (var dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Stock_voorlopig$]", dbConnection))
using (var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbCommand))
{
    da.Fill(ds, "Stock");
}

var joined = from rType in ds.Tables["HWTypes"].AsEnumerable()
             join rStock in ds.Tables["Stock"].AsEnumerable()
             on rType.Field<string>("ProductID") equals rStock.Field<string>("Partno")
             select new
             {
                 ProductID = rType.Field<string>("ProductID")
                 // add the other columns you need here
             };


GridView1.DataSource = joined;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

**Edit 1:**

I am trying to do something like this:

```
private static DataTable JoinDataTablesWithLinq()
{

 //rest of the code from above
 return joined.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
The type 'AnonymousType#1' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Data.DataRow'.
```

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate (which @TimSchmelter also commented on:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382343/linq-to-datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to do something like this:

```
private static DataTable JoinDataTablesWithLinq()
{

 //rest of the code from above
 return joined.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

You cannot create a `DataTable` "on the fly". You have selected an anonymous type which is not a `IEnumerable<DataRow>` which you need to use [`CopyToDataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx). So you either have to use a custom class and fill a `List<MyClass>` with all properties you need to persist it or you have to create a `DataTable` with all necessary `DataColumns` of the anonymous type and fill that.

You see that it's not that easy. There's one dynamic approach though. But that requires reflection, therefore it's  not efficient at all.

Here we go... (extract of [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9259348/284240))

You could build your own [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx) that takes any kind of IEnumerable(not only `DataRow`)and returns a new `DataTable`:

Here is the implementation (with help of [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx#Y105)):

```
public class ObjectShredder<T> {
    private System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] _fi;
    private System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] _pi;
    private System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int> _ordinalMap;
    private System.Type _type;

    // ObjectShredder constructor.
    public ObjectShredder() {
        _type = typeof(T);
        _fi = _type.GetFields();
        _pi = _type.GetProperties();
        _ordinalMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads a DataTable from a sequence of objects.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The sequence of objects to load into the DataTable.</param>
    /// <param name="table">The input table. The schema of the table must match that 
    /// the type T.  If the table is null, a new table is created with a schema 
    /// created from the public properties and fields of the type T.</param>
    /// <param name="options">Specifies how values from the source sequence will be applied to 
    /// existing rows in the table.</param>
    /// <returns>A DataTable created from the source sequence.</returns>
    public DataTable Shred(IEnumerable<T> source, DataTable table, LoadOption? options) {
        // Load the table from the scalar sequence if T is a primitive type.
        if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive) {
            return ShredPrimitive(source, table, options);
        }

        // Create a new table if the input table is null.
        if (table == null) {
            table = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
        }

        // Initialize the ordinal map and extend the table schema based on type T.
        table = ExtendTable(table, typeof(T));

        // Enumerate the source sequence and load the object values into rows.
        table.BeginLoadData();
        using (IEnumerator<T> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            while (e.MoveNext()) {
                if (options != null) {
                    table.LoadDataRow(ShredObject(table, e.Current), (LoadOption)options);
                } else {
                    table.LoadDataRow(ShredObject(table, e.Current), true);
                }
            }
        }
        table.EndLoadData();

        // Return the table.
        return table;
    }

    public DataTable ShredPrimitive(IEnumerable<T> source, DataTable table, LoadOption? options) {
        // Create a new table if the input table is null.
        if (table == null) {
            table = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
        }

        if (!table.Columns.Contains("Value")) {
            table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(T));
        }

        // Enumerate the source sequence and load the scalar values into rows.
        table.BeginLoadData();
        using (IEnumerator<T> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            Object[] values = new object[table.Columns.Count];
            while (e.MoveNext()) {
                values[table.Columns["Value"].Ordinal] = e.Current;

                if (options != null) {
                    table.LoadDataRow(values, (LoadOption)options);
                } else {
                    table.LoadDataRow(values, true);
                }
            }
        }
        table.EndLoadData();

        // Return the table.
        return table;
    }

    public object[] ShredObject(DataTable table, T instance) {

        FieldInfo[] fi = _fi;
        PropertyInfo[] pi = _pi;

        if (instance.GetType() != typeof(T)) {
            // If the instance is derived from T, extend the table schema
            // and get the properties and fields.
            ExtendTable(table, instance.GetType());
            fi = instance.GetType().GetFields();
            pi = instance.GetType().GetProperties();
        }

        // Add the property and field values of the instance to an array.
        Object[] values = new object[table.Columns.Count];
        foreach (FieldInfo f in fi) {
            values[_ordinalMap[f.Name]] = f.GetValue(instance);
        }

        foreach (PropertyInfo p in pi) {
            values[_ordinalMap[p.Name]] = p.GetValue(instance, null);
        }

        // Return the property and field values of the instance.
        return values;
    }

    public DataTable ExtendTable(DataTable table, Type type) {
        // Extend the table schema if the input table was null or if the value 
        // in the sequence is derived from type T.            
        foreach (FieldInfo f in type.GetFields()) {
            if (!_ordinalMap.ContainsKey(f.Name)) {
                // Add the field as a column in the table if it doesn't exist
                // already.
                DataColumn dc = table.Columns.Contains(f.Name) ? table.Columns[f.Name]
                    : table.Columns.Add(f.Name, f.FieldType);

                // Add the field to the ordinal map.
                _ordinalMap.Add(f.Name, dc.Ordinal);
            }
        }
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in type.GetProperties()) {
            if (!_ordinalMap.ContainsKey(p.Name)) {
                // Add the property as a column in the table if it doesn't exist
                // already.
                DataColumn dc = table.Columns.Contains(p.Name) ? table.Columns[p.Name]
                    : table.Columns.Add(p.Name, p.PropertyType);

                // Add the property to the ordinal map.
                _ordinalMap.Add(p.Name, dc.Ordinal);
            }
        }

        // Return the table.
        return table;
    }
}
```

Now you can add these extensions:

```
public static class CustomLINQtoDataSetMethods {
    public static DataTable CopyToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
        return new ObjectShredder<T>().Shred(source, null, null);
    }

    public static DataTable CopyToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                                DataTable table, LoadOption? options) {
        return new ObjectShredder<T>().Shred(source, table, options);
    }  
}
```

Voilà! Now `CopyToDataTable` works with any kind of `IEnumerable<T>` :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. I will continue with what you advised.